# What's the word for the action of using a one-time special offer?

Tags: single-word-requests

What's the word for the action of using a one-time special offer? I mean on that can be used by more than one person but each person can only use it once.

I'm looking for the word that describes the action and not the result.

If "X people each used a one-time special offer", so "the special offer has been "**something**"ed X times".

Would it be "excercised" or does that have connotations of a non-single-use action?

Maybe "redeemed"? But I'm not sure if it pertains to the actual "cashing-in" action (whatever it may involve - coupon, proof of some kind of membership or whatever). Maybe it's just a description of the result that the offer is "used-up".

Or is the right word maybe "claimed"?

What's the word that would fit the "something" above?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Like you mention, I think [redeem](https://www.wordnik.com/words/redeem) is the word you're looking for:

> #### redeem
>
> *transitive verb* To turn in (coupons, for example) and receive something in exchange.
>
> *transitive verb* To convert into cash.
>
> *transitive verb* To fulfill (a pledge, for example).

Depending on the context, you might also use "exchange," but it seems that "redeem" is your best option.

Answer (score 0):

As you say, the offer may take a form where *redeemed* doesn't make any sense.

For instance, a visitor may say to their host:

> "I'm leaving tomorrow and you won't see me again. Would you like me to make you cook you a really unique breakfast?"

Idiomatically, this could be considered a "one-time special offer." It's not something that will be repeated, and the guest is offering to do something for the host.

In this situation, using the word *redeem* would be inappropriate. It's a verbal offer, not one that involves a coupon that can be exchanged for something.

A more general term for what you want—and which would apply in every case—is **take advantage of**.

For instance:

> I *took advantage of* his offer of breakfast.
>   I *took advantage of* the movie coupon.

The fact that you can add whatever object is needed in the second part of the sentence means that it can apply to anything—a person, a situation, or a coupon. In contrast, *redeemed* (or *exercised* or *claimed*) would only apply in some specific situations.

---

Note that Merriam-Webster has a specific entry for the phrase *take advantage of*. It comes under the much more comprehensive entry for the word [*take*](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/take):

> **1** : to make good use of
>   // *Take advantage of* your free time.